# Reading package contents into an array of classes

Tags: java

Is it possible to read the contents of a package into an array of Class objects? Currently I have something that looks like the following in my code

```
static Class<?>[] classArray = {
        ServerNameRsp.class,
        ConfigCompleteRsp.class};
```

Both 'ServerNameRsp' and 'ConfigCompleteRsp' are in the same package and as the package grows it would be ideal to not have to hard code all the added classes to this array. Is there a way to read in the contents of a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) java library, you can do this:

```
SubTypesScanner sts = new SubTypesScanner(false); /* false means include direct Object subtypes in results.*/
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("Your.package.name", sts);
Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
for (Class<? extends Object> clazz : classes) {
    System.out.println(clazz);
}
```

Comment: The package name that I am using is Appliance and it is directly under src. When I use your code with a package name of "Appliance" classes.size() always returns 0, despite there being classes in the Appliance package. The classes in the package are standard subclasses of Object